# Script PowerShell para descarga Excel de Sharepoint Online

Tags: excel, script, powershell, windows-server

Estoy creando un script que se conecte a Sharepoint Online usando unas credenciales almacenadas en Credential Manager. El server es un Windows Server 2016 que tiene instalado SharePoint Online Client Components SDK.

Cuando ejecuto el PowerShell de me da un error que reza: *Error: A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.*

No se que hace falta para ejecutar el script. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Aquí el script (el usuario y la clave las he puesto en el código, para prueba):

```
    #Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

   
#Variables for Processing
$FileURL = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/blablabla/YXRlZFVzZXIiOmZhbHNlfQ%3D%3D"
$ListName ="Documents"
$DestinationFolderPath="D:\Prioridades_LIMS\Ranking"
$UserName = "user@dominio"
$Password = "password"
 
#Get Credentials to connect
#$Cred = Get-Credential
$Cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))

  
Try { 

 #Set up the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Cred
    $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
 
    #powershell sharepoint online get file by url
    $File = $Ctx.web.GetFileByUrl($FileURL)
    $Ctx.Load($File)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Copy-PnPFile -Path $File.FullName -Folder $DestinationFolderPath -ErrorAction Stop -Overwrite
    Write-host "File Size:" ($File.Length/1KB)  
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -Foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

El objeto ClientContext necesita la URL del sitio para poder establecer un contexto para las operaciones de SharePoint. Por lo tanto, necesitarás proporcionar la URL del sitio de SharePoint Online.

```
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
```

y la variable $SiteURL no esta definida en tu script. Declarala en
#Variables for Processing

```
$SiteUrl = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/s/blablabla"
```

Ya me dices que tal, porque igual te fallan mas cosas...